# Can't load websites on port 2096. Load through proxy?

Tags: proxy

I'm trying to load my personal webmail, which loads on port 2096.  Internet Explorer displays a page cannot be displayed.  All other websites on port 80 work fine.

I am also having trouble loading cPanel, which also loads on port 2096.

It looks like my corporate firewall or proxy is blocking this port number.  I have added exceptions for this port to the firewall on our proxy server, but it didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an [anonymous proxy](http://www.the-cloak.com/) which loaded the site for me.